# java sql statement inserting variable

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I have this issue where I want the `table_name` to be a variable passed in during the method being called. This SQL statement seems to be a issue.

```
String table_name = "table1";
preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("insert into db."+table_name +"values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Comment: `"+table_name +"values` probably needs a space between table name and `values`, otherwise it reads "`table1values`"

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/

Comment: String statement = "insert into eamonn_db."+table_name +" values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        
        preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(statement);

Comment: i've tried & it doesnt work

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **exact** error message you get. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [edit] your question do **not** post code or additional information in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a space before `"values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")`?

Have you tried with `" values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")`?

EDIT: Can you verify the value of sql is `"insert into db.table1 values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"`. I don't think it is the case at all.

```
String table_name = "table1";
String sql = "insert into db."+table_name +"values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
System.out.println(sql);
preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and give us the exception that you are getting? Just saying it doesn't work is not enough for us to help you :)

Comment: Also the table structure and how you are setting the variables for the prepare statement.

Comment: ive previously successfully imported from eclipse to mysql. After i tried to insert this table_name as a variable that can be changed by user, it prompts me

Comment: So you mean you still get the syntax error without the variable?
 `connect.prepareStatement("insert into db.table1 values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")`

Comment: no. it will not have error if i use connect.prepareStatement("insert into db.table1 values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")

Comment: Hi, it has been solve! Thank you so much! I forgotten to insert the table name in my yml file! It was out of carelessness !